# Move around contents of window at the click of a button?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-interface

I have a window containing 6 NSView subclasses. My views are placed beside each other horizontally, creating one long horizontal rectangle window.

When the user clicks on a button, I want the same views to be moved and placed vertically, creating one long vertical rectangle window.

e.g. Currently my views are placed as: [][][][][][]

At the click of a button, I want my views to move into the following new places:

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

[]

How can I do this? Note I am developing an app for OSX Mountain Lion. I also do not want to create new NSViews, I just want them to move them around into the new order.

Comment: This will have to be done programatically, using `NSView`'s `-setFrame:`

Comment: @Vervious I see. I would also need to change the shape of the window though (make it a vertical rectangle from a horizontal rectangle). How would I do this?

Comment: Once again programmatically, except (I believe) using `NSWindow`'s `-setFrame:display:animate:` or `-setFrame:display:` after calculating the window's new size.